# How to get onblur and onfocus to work in php script?

Tags: php, javascript

I want to add a small functionality to a newsletter script, however I can't get it done properly as it results in errors in Dreamweaver:

My original code:

```
    $data.='<input style="float:left; margin-right:10px;" type="text" id="'.$formidreal.'-wysija-to" class="'.$classValidate.'" name="wysija[user][email]" />';
```

I would like to add the following:

```
    value="example@email.com" onblur="if (this.value == ''){this.value = 'example@email.com'; }" onfocus="if (this.value == 'example@email.com') {this.value = ''; }"
```

I am prett y sure that is has to be formatted differently to get working within PHP altough I am unable to figure it out.

Some expert advise would be very much appreciated.

Thank you very much,
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you are trying to do here.

Consider using [HTML5 Placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp), that is more semantic (or if you do I.E 7.0 support then, perhaps JS is OK).

If you are comfortable with JQuery, use it.

If not, learn it.

If cannot learn now... then, PHP Code should be:

```
$data.='<input style="float:left; margin-right:10px;" type="text" id="'.$formidreal.'-wysija-to" class="'.$classValidate.'" name="wysija[user][email]"." value=\"example@email.com\" onblur=\"if (this.value == ''){this.value = \'example@email.com\'; }\" onfocus=\"if (this.value == \'example@email.com\') {this.value = ''; }\"" />';
```

However, I would STILL recommend that you DO NOT OPT for INLINE JS.

PS: I might have made a mistake here in the code but logic is to escape using

```
\
```

for single and double quotes that you wish to be displayed within HTML but not compiled as end or start of a string.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Thank you KarmicDice - it seems to be working just fine. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Some advice would be not to put full javascript inside your html attributes.

Try calling a function then doing your logic inside the function.

It's much neater if you use stuff like jQuery's selectors to separate the two. :)

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Jared!

Answer (score 1):

You should write like this:

```
value="example@email.com" onblur="if (this.value == \'\'){this.value = \'example@email.com\'; }" onfocus="if (this.value == \'example@email.com\') {this.value = \'\'; }"
```